# ManyToMany model fileld check number of update or add using m2m signals

Tags: django, m2m

My Question: ManyToMany model fileld check number of update or add using m2m signals
Here is my django code:

```
class SlamQuestion(models.Model):
    slam = models.OneToOneField(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    question = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.slam.usercode
```

Comment: please format your question, and add your question/issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def m2m_save_slam_question(sender, instance, action, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.question.through.objects.all().count() > 2:
        raise Exception(f'{self.slam.usercode} allredy 2 Question Is added')

m2m_changed.connect(m2m_save_slam_question, sender=SlamQuestion.question.through)
```